# how to check an array if each following value is greater than the last

Tags: php

i am trying to find a way to validate some numbers in a php array, checking if each value is its greater than the last value.

Here is an example:

```
$number['num1']=1;
$number['num2']=2;
$number['num3']=3;
$number['num4']=4;

if($number['num1'] > $number['num2'] || $number['num1'] > $number['num3'] || 
$number['num1'] > $number['num4']){

//Some error
}

i can manually check each but is there an easier way, any suggestions?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this pretty easily with a simple loop and using the PHP array pointer functions `next` and `current`:

```
$array = [1,2,3,4];
$isValid = true;
$current = current($array);
while($next = next($array)) {
    if($next <= $current) {
        $isValid = false;
        break;
    }
    $current = $next;
}

var_dump($isValid);
```

Example: http://ideone.com/3uHPMq

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that the OP will have to restructure the array to have numeric keys like this.

Comment: thanks alot brother. works great. @Mike, i have already done this. thanks again guys. :)

Comment: @Mike - Internal pointers don't care about the keys. This will work with non numeric keys. Example: http://ideone.com/rsMLt6

Answer (score 2):

Scopey beat me to it, but here's what I did:

```
$number['nums'][4] = 4;
$number['nums'][2] = 2;
$number['nums'][1] = 600;
$number['nums'][3] = 3;
// Note, I rearranged the order above just to make sure it 
// works no matter what order the values get put in

function isAscending($arr) {
    ksort($arr);

    for ($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++) {
        if (isset($arr[$i-1])) {
            if ($arr[$i-1] > $arr[$i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

var_dump(isAscending($number['nums'])); // false
```